# creating function in oracle using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I  want to create a function in oracle using vb.net in many databases using loop. I am using this query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION promo_code_fun(store_id IN VARCHAR2,ws_id IN VARCHAR2,trn_id IN VARCHAR2,business_dt IN VARCHAR2,line_no IN integer,item_cd IN VARCHAR2,creation_time timestamp)
```

the problem is it is creating function but with errors.. in oracle it is automatically adding a schema name before the function name. I have passed schema name through vb code. but it creates function with errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION " & """" & SchemaName & """" & ".promo_code_fun(store_id IN VARCHAR2,ws_id IN VARCHAR2,trn_id IN VARCHAR2,business_dt IN VARCHAR2,line_no IN integer,item_cd IN VARCHAR2,creation_time timestamp)
```

if i am copying this code in toad editor and running it manually it creates the function with no errors..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "23914".promo_code_fun(store_id IN VARCHAR2,ws_id IN VARCHAR2,trn_id IN VARCHAR2,business_dt IN VARCHAR2,line_no IN integer,item_cd IN VARCHAR2,creation_time timestamp)
```

while running manually w/o double quotes it is giving error.

Comment: Why do you want to use a VB front-end for creating stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm):

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

Hence if you want to use a schema name of 23914 is must be encloded in double-quotes.